# Keyword not supported: 'userid' error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have cloned this source code (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Onion-Architecture-In-9c58c06d). I am using mysql and my connection string

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;userid=root;pwd=root;port=3306;database=ddd;sslmode=none;"
  },
```

In my package manager console command `Add-Migration FirstMigration` was successful however, `Update-Database` is throwing me

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'userid'.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Keyword not supported: 'userid'.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where's the code? What database? That's not a valid SQL Server connection string. You can't use a connection string meant eg for Oracle with SQL Server or MySQL.

Comment: BTW what you posted here looks *nothing* like the connection string in the sample. The call stack shows that you tried to execute migration code using a *SQL Server* provider while the connection string clearly targets another database. How did you configure the contexts and the migrations?

Answer (score 18):

That's not a valid connection string for SQL Server. `userid` should be `User ID` and `pwd` should be `Password`. For example

```
Server=servername\instancename;Database=dbname;User Id=username;Password=password;
```

For more examples see:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Thanks! If I have to use mysql instead, how to go about it? In nuget package manager many packages were to updated but it fails saying packpackage restore fail. It does not allow me to install EntityFrameworkCore.MySql as well

Answer (score 0):

The code you referenced uses MsSQL. If you wish to you use mysql you need to change the code.

In the reference code, there is a class named `Startup.cs`.

There is a line in the method `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` that you need to change.

Currently the line states:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

In short: Add the a DbContext of type `ApplicationContext` to the services collection. To instantiate an instance use these options:

`UseSqlServer` with a connection string named `DefaultConnection`

You need to change those options to reflect mysql.

---

### Possible solution

1. Install package [MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore)
2. Change the line to:

```
services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```